# How to Save a UI Image Rotation and Load it When Coming Back from a Different Scene in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, image-rotation

In my 2D game the player should be able to rotate a UI Image based on a Mouse Drag function, and then press the "Go" button to start the level, and after this the "Back" button on the level should take the player back to the main scene (the one that has the UI Image), thus the image should be displayed in the same last rotation the player has set for it. Everything works fantastically fine for me except for the part of loading the image rotation. I was able to see the correct rotation value in the console, however I see no rotation on the image when coming back from the other scene. I've been trying to do so many attempts to make it work but not getting any good results. It will be so much appreciated if you help me celebrate my birthday tomorrow!

I hope this will explain better what I am trying to do:

1. First scene where the square is the UI Image and the Go button is under
2. After the user drags the image, it gets a new rotation. Then the player clicks the Go button, the rotation is saved and a new scene will be displayed.
3. And then there is a second scene that has the Back button (it takes the user to the main scene and should display the rotated UI image based on the last user's input). **The issue is that there is no rotation shown at all on the UI Image.**

And here is the code I have used for the UI Image Rotation:

```
public static Quaternion rot;

public void OnMouseDrag(){
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
        Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = rot;
        rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward); 

}
```

And this is the code assigned to the "Go" Button in the first scene:

```
 public void OnClicked(Button button)
 {
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PlayerX", ImgRotation.rot.eulerAngles.x);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PlayerY", ImgRotation.rot.eulerAngles.y);
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("PlayerZ", ImgRotation.rot.eulerAngles.z);
     Application.LoadLevel ("2");
 }
```

And the code assigned to the "Back" button in the second scene:

```
 public void OnClicked(Button button)
 {

     Vector3 imgRot;
     imgRot = ImgRotation.rot.eulerAngles;
     imgRot.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerX");
     imgRot.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerY");
     imgRot.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerZ");
     print (imgRot.z);
     Application.LoadLevel ("1");
 }
```

Comment: You don't see the image rotated, because you didn't rotate it. You have Vector3, but you didn't assign (just printed) it to the gameobject in your script for the "Back" button.

Comment: @buxter I have tried to assign it in the BackButtonScript but each time I get this error message: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. And I used this Script: ImgRotation temp = this.GetComponent<ImgRotation>();
  Vector3 imgTrans;
  imgTrans = temp.img.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
  imgTrans.z = imgRot.z;

Comment: Can you paste the whole script, please? As well, ImgRotation -> that's your script, not an image.

Comment: @buxter What I was trying to do is to get the referenced image from that script as the ImgRotation is attached to the UI Image.

Comment: @buxter this is my ImgRotation Script: using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ImgRotation : MonoBehaviour {

 public static Quaternion rot;
 public Image img;


 public void OnMouseDrag(){
    
   Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
   Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
   float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
   transform.rotation = rot;
   rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward); 

 
 }

}

Comment: @buxter and this the BackButtonScript:

public class BackButtonScript : MonoBehaviour {


 public static Vector3 imgRot;

 public void OnClicked(Button button)
 {
          imgRot = ImgRotation.rot.eulerAngles;
  imgRot.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerX");
  imgRot.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerY");
  imgRot.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerZ");
  print (imgRot.z);
  Application.LoadLevel ("1");
  ImgRotation temp = GetComponent<ImgRotation> ();
  Vector3 imgTrans;
  imgTrans = temp.img.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
  imgTrans.z = imgRot.z;

 }
}

Comment: Firstly, having code snippets in comments is not nice. ;) Secondly, if you are using Image from UnityEngine.UI, you need RectTransform, img.rectTransform

Comment: img.rectTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, z);

Comment: @buxter thank you very much! I have tried another attempt and it worked for me! I will post the answer now!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not seeing the rotation is because you're never setting it on the actual image object. You can't do this from the back button because the image object won't exist in that scene.

Simply load the settings on Awake instead:

```
void Awake()
{
    Vector3 imgRot;
    imgRot.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerX");
    imgRot.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerY");
    imgRot.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerZ");

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(imgRot);
}
```

Keep in mind that this setting will be persisted between the game closing down and starting back up. If that's not the behaviour you're after, see below for a possible example on how to persist these sorts of settings between scenes.

Rather than using the PlayerPrefs to store this information between scenes, consider having an object that uses DontDestroyOnLoad to persist the data.

for example, you could have an object in the scene that looks something like this:

```
public class RotationStorage : public MonoBehaviour
{
    private Quaternion m_imageRotation = Quaternion.identity;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }

    void SetRotation(Quaternion rotation)
    {
        m_imageRotation = rotation;
    }

    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        if (Application.loadedLevelName == "Your starting scene")
        {
            GameObject image = GameObject.Find("name of your object");
            //If the rotation hasn't been set yet don't set the image' rotation.
            if(image != null && m_rotation != Quaternion.identity)
            {
                image.transform.rotation = m_imageRotation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, inside the script on the image you're rotating, you'd keep a reference to the RotationStorage gameObject and store your current rotation in that whenever OnMouseDrag is called:

```
private RotationStorage m_storage = null;

void Awake()
{
    m_storage = FindObjectOfType<RotationStorage>();
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
    Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = rot;
    rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward);

    m_storage.SetRotation(rot);
}
```

To ensure you don't get duplicate copies of the RotationStorage object, you'd want to set it up in a scene that only ever gets loaded once, i.e. a splash screen on start-up.

Comment: many thanks for the great help provided! I really really appreciate it. I have tried another solution a bit before seeing your answer and it worked for me. I also tried your solution and got a NullReferenceException at this line: m_storage.SetRotation(rot);. I will post my answer right now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

So finally I got my problem solved! I have added a boolean static variable in the Back Button Script so whenever the button is pressed and it takes the player to the first scene, the boolean will turn true. And in the other side in the imgRotation Script I have added a Start() function so whenever the scene starts it will rotate the image based on the last user's input.

So this is the BackButtonScript:

```
public static Vector3 imgRot;
[HideInInspector] public static bool loadRot=false;


public void OnClicked(Button button)
{
    imgRot = ImgRotation.rot.eulerAngles;
    imgRot.x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerX");
    imgRot.y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerY");
    imgRot.z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("PlayerZ");


    loadRot= true;
    Application.LoadLevel ("1");
}
```

And this is the ImgRotation Script:

```
public static Quaternion rot;


void Start(){

    if (BackButtonScript.loadRot == true) {
        transform.Rotate(BackButtonScript.imgRot);

    }
}


public void OnMouseDrag(){

        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (transform.position);
        Vector3 dir = Input.mousePosition - pos;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = rot;
        rot = Quaternion.AngleAxis (angle, Vector3.forward); 


}
```

Hope it helps! :)